# Render data from DataTables to lowercase

Tags: datatables

I need to render data returned by dataTables to lowercase. I've search the net but can't find any post on the subject. Convert "ImageName" content to lowercase before displaying. My code is:

```
{ data: 'ImageName',  "sWidth": "20%",  render : function (data, type) 
    { return '<img src="' + imagepath + '' +data+'" class="WayfinderSignageImage"/>'; }
},
```

Comment: Using `data.toLowerCase()` should work in this context: `return '<img src="' + imagepath + '' + data.toLowerCase() + '" class="WayfinderSignageImage"/>';`.

Comment: @andrewjames, many thanks, perfect.